# looping issue, the while loop executes an extra iteration

Tags: c, while-loop

**Program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char t;
    while(1) {
        t='\0';
        printf("\nExit?(y/n): ");
        scanf("%c", &t);
        if( t=='y' || t=='Y') {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        printf("\nContinuing...");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ vim Return.c
$ gcc -o Return Return.c
$ ./Return

Exit?(y/n): n

Continuing...
Exit?(y/n):
Continuing...
Exit?(y/n): n

Continuing...
Exit?(y/n):
Continuing...
Exit?(y/n): y
$
```

after giving `'n'` as input, the

```
Continuing...
Exit?(y/n):
```

loops for one more time, with out taking input from user. If there any mistake in code , please let me know

Comment: You've forgotten about the newline after the `y`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that `scanf` discards the newline. Try like this:

```
scanf(" %c", &t);
```

Comment: just curious to know how it takes new line as input, because '%c' takes only one character as input right?

Comment: @DragonX:- The difference between scanf("%c", &c1) and scanf(" %c", &c2) is that the format without the blank reads the next character, even if it is white space, whereas the one with the blank skips white space (including newlines) and reads the next character that is not white space. The "Enter" keypress sends a '\n' to standard input which is what is scanned by your second scanf call.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving space in format identifier of scanf statement. try something like

```
scanf(" %c",&t);
```

Comment: sorry for the typo in scanf.